# How to display some selected user meta data on a specific page with a shortcode?

Tags: shortcode, user-meta

I need to display on some specific pages some selected user meta data (not all), for some users.

On the [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta#Getting_all_meta_data) page for the `get_user_meta()` function we have this example (user_id = 9):

```
<?php
  $all_meta_for_user = get_user_meta( 9 );
  print_r( $all_meta_for_user );
?>
```

The results of this example:

```
Array ( [first_name] => Array ( [0] => Tom ) [last_name] => Array ( [0] => Auger) [nickname] => Array ( [0] => tomauger ) [description] => etc.... )
```

And a **Note** (shortened):

> ... you may want to run a simple array_map() on the results of get_user_meta() in order to take only the first index of each result (this emulating what the $single argument does when $key is provided:

```
if( $all_meta_for_user = get_user_meta( $user_id ) ) 
    $all_meta_for_user = array_map( function( $a ){ return $a[0]; }, get_user_meta( $user_id ) );

  print_r( $all_meta_for_user );
```

The result:

```
Array ( [first_name] => Tom [last_name] => Auger [nickname] => tomauger [description] => etc.... )
```

**My question is:**

How to put this in a function that will display, for example, the user last and first names with a shortcode (but really I need more user meta data)?

What I mean? On a specific page we put a shortcode with the user ID and the related function must return the meta data for each selected key of this user. Is this possible? Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you asking how to convert the information in an array into formatted HTML? That is a pure PHP question and will be off topic here, per the [faq]

Comment: @faq – s_ha_dum No, this is simple. I need a Wordpress specific function and a shortcode for that function.

Comment: Not sure what the question is? A WordPress function for what? You've pulled the user meta data. The display is up to you. That is why I thought you were asking how to convert that array into HTML. The WordPress part of building a shortcode is easy but you need to write the callback to convert that information to HTML. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, if I understand you correctly. I want to display the user meta data (only for specific keys) on a custom user page.

Comment: If you are building a custom user page you don't need a shortcode. You can write the code into the post template. Still confused. @Bainternet posted a simple shortcode but I get the feeling that still isn't what you need, or isn't all you need.

Comment: This function and shortcode will be for multiple pages/users.

Comment: [*Coming from another Q&A*](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/83267/how-to-display-the-names-of-users-from-a-specific-group-with-a-shortcode/83289#comment113419_83289). Much probably with the Codex example and @bainternet's Answer you could build your desired output. :::: I think what's missing in your Q is: **1)** How your shortcode would look like? `[shortcode atts='example']` **2)** What output do you expect from it?

Comment: @brasofilo I added my own answer that, I think, includes what is missing in the original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the simplest shortcode that will do the job for you

```
add_shortcode('USER_META', 'user_meta_shortcode_handler');
/**
 * User Meta Shortcode handler
 * usage: [USER_META user_id=1 meta="first_name"]
 * @param  array $atts   
 * @param  string $content
 * @return stirng
 */
function user_meta_shortcode_handler($atts,$content=null){
    return esc_html(get_user_meta($atts['user_id'], $atts['meta'], true));
}
```

USAGE:

```
[USER_META user_id=1 meta="first_name"]
[USER_META user_id=1 meta="last_name"]
```

Comment: but maybe esc_html() or htmlspecialchars() before returning...

Comment: @webaware true!

Answer (score 0):

Bellow you can see the adapted code of @Bainternet (thank you!) that I use currently. Now I can display with only one row/shortcode a big list of only custom user metadata that I need, in a custom order and formatted specifically for each type of input (text field input or textarea). Maybe the code can look better if I could get and display (HTML formatted) all the user meta data at once, excluding maybe a few, but this is too hard for me. Here is only an excerpt of the list of custom user metadata that I need to display, in reality it is longer.

```
add_shortcode( 'user_meta', 'user_meta_shortcode_handler' );
/**
 * User Meta Shortcode handler
 * usage: [user_meta user_id=1]
 * @param  array $atts   
 * @param  string $content
 * @return string
 */
function user_meta_shortcode_handler( $atts, $content=null ) {
    $output = "";
    echo '<div class="academic">';
    echo '<h3>Teaching position</h3>';
    echo esc_html( get_user_meta( $atts['user_id'], 'teaching_position', true ) );
    echo '<h3>Scientific title</h3>';
    echo esc_html( get_user_meta( $atts['user_id'], 'scientific_title', true ) );
    echo '<h3>Publications</h3>';
    echo wpautop( get_user_meta( $atts['user_id'], 'publications', true ) );
    echo '</div><!-- .academic -->';
}
```

Comment: For a better formatting of paragraphs I changed the `echo wpautop(...` in the way suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523961/paragraphs-in-textarea). Can this be improved?