# How to display the names of users from a specific group with a shortcode?

Tags: shortcode, users

I have in the database a table with the `user_id` and corresponding `group_id` values, so each row contain the ID of the user that is a member of a group and the related group ID. **The question is**: How to display the names of users from a specific group, plus some metadata, with a shortcode, for example `[group_members group_id=1]`? With the bellow function, that I try to adapt for this without success, I can to display only the user ID or the group ID.

```
add_shortcode( 'group_members',  'group_members_shortcode_handler' );

function group_members_shortcode_handler ( $atts, $content = null ) {    

  global $wpdb;
  $querystr = "SELECT * FROM wp_groups_user_group";
  $users = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);

  foreach ($users as $user) {
    $output .= $user->group_id;
  }

 return $output;
}
```

Comment: There's no enough information to provide an Answer (unless someone is familiar with this plugin). Hopefully, you already read the [documentation](http://www.itthinx.com/plugins/groups/) and checked the [code](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/groups/tags/1.3.7/groups.php), right?

Comment: @brasofilo What information is needed? I can make the question more general, so not related to the Groups plugin. In this case we know only the table name (`wp_groups_user_group`), columns names (`user_id` and `group_id`). This is not enough?

Comment: Did you tried their [support](http://www.itthinx.com/support/)? They also have an [API](http://www.itthinx.com/documentation/groups/api/). Otherwise, try to build a shortcode with a custom [`$wpdb`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%24wpdb+is%3Aanswer).

Comment: @brasofilo I updated my question, also added a draft code that I can't finish. Please, help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is my own answer to the question. I will appreciate any constructive comment.

```
add_shortcode( 'group_members',  'group_members_shortcode_handler' );

function group_members_shortcode_handler ( $atts, $content = null ) {    

  global $wpdb;
  $querystr = "SELECT * FROM wp_groups_user_group";
  $users = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);

  $output='';
  foreach ($users as $user) {
    if($user->group_id == $atts['group_id']){
      $firstName = esc_html(get_user_meta($user->user_id, 'first_name', true));
      $lastName = esc_html(get_user_meta($user->user_id, 'last_name', true));
      $output .= '<li>' . $firstName . ' ' . $lastName . ' - ' . esc_html(get_user_meta($user->user_id, 'teaching_position', true)) . '</li>' . PHP_EOL;
    }
  }

  return $output;
}
```

Comment: Looks ok, glad you sorted this out! Maybe, as good practice, declare `$output='';` before the foreach loop. And you could grab [all user meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta#Getting_all_meta_data) at once.

Comment: Oh, as we can see in that other Q&A, do an `esc_html` in all `get_user_meta`. :::: I'll comment over there about the specific *all user meta* issue.

Comment: @brasofilo I updated the code as you suggested. I changed also to `esc_html` the `esc_attr` for the last `get_user_meta` from `foreach` loop. I think the code now is OK. Thank you!